# Confluent serdes with protobuf specific messages not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I'm having a hard time understanding the usage of Confluent serdes apis. I'm using Confluent platform (7.2.2) schema registry with protobuf and intend to use specific message classes in my Kafka streams application.

Following is an example from [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#further-serdes):

```java
private static KafkaProtobufSerde<Message> createConfiguredSerdeForRecordValues() {
  SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient = new SchemaRegistryClient();
  KafkaProtobufSerde<Message> serde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<>(schemaRegistryClient);
  Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
  serdeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "demo");
  serde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
  return serde;
}
```

In version 7.2.2, `SchemaRegistryClient` is abstract. In its place, I used

```java
var schemaClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegUrl, 100);
var assetKeySerde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<>(schemaClient, AssetKey.class);
var assetConfigSerde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<>(schemaClient, AssetConfig.class);
```

and then ultimately:

```java
KTable<AssetKey, AssetConfig> assetTable = builder.table(assetTopic, Consumed.with(assetKeySerde, assetConfigSerde));
```

Here `AssetKey` and `AssetConfig` are my protobuf generated classes. However, even when passing the `schemaClient` and protobuf classes in this constructor, it still expects me to pass schema registry url and protobuf class in a map to `.configure()`. Then what's the point of the constructor that I'm using above? With this config, I get an error

```
com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage cannot be cast to class AssetKey
```

If I pass a map in `.configure()` with `schema.registry.url` and `specific.protobuf.key.type`, I get an exception saying invalid schema. The schema is valid though, and my producer can successfully post to the topic.

Is there a complete example that I can refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the example from the tutorials https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/changing-serialization-format/kstreams.html, with source code being at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-tutorials/blob/master/_includes/tutorials/serialization/kstreams/code/src/main/java/io/confluent/developer/serialization/SerializationTutorial.java ?

I think the constructor that passes a `SchemaRegistryClient` into `KafkaProtobufSerde` is for testing purposes only. Setting the properties should be sufficient.

Comment: I got it working by just using the config map and ignored that constructor.